# EF Core get query from IQueryable and add some filter

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core and need to see which SQL code is generated.

I want to change it (add more filters or add join for some columns that I need in my `Where` clause; I don't want to select some column from join)

Comment: Don't go this path. Use the LINQ query itself to add predicates (filters). There are more possibilities than you think. You need to show the class model + LINQ query and explain what you're trying to achieve if you want more detailed help.

Comment: in this project, filters are generated runtime. I use DynamicLINQ  and for this Filter "Name == 'test' " is OK  but in other cases   filter like this "Request.document.name == 'test' " for this  case I need join and then filter

Comment: Should be possible with dynamic LINQ as well. But maybe you should consider using expressions instead of dynamic LINQ. Expressions can also be composed at runtime and there are predicate builders out there to make it easier. Anyway, modifying dynamically generated SQL in a safe and robust manner is virtually impossible.